# Can we use apache Tika without Java but with JDK so I can provide it with the exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, apache-tika, inno-setup-v6

When deployed as an exe in python tika requires java right

so I installed open JDK but the tika still shows unable to start server
do have to change environment variables and if so then when

Comment: Does `java -version` work?

Comment: @Gagravarr it does!!** But then why is it still not working? DO I need to specify path to server.jar or server.jar.md5 or the jdk. Also this is what it shows when I go to the audiobook(name of my exe made by python)'s directory and type this:C:\Program Files (x86)\Audiobook\jdk-11.0.11+9\bin>java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK Client VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)

Comment: You might be better off reporting this as a bug against Chris Mattman's Tika Python project, at first glance if Java is properly working then it ought to be able to call it, so may be a windows-specific bug

Comment: @Gagravarr yeah but what if i have to specify the path of the JRE/JDK or maybe path of server.jar, I haven't done that